# How to print matrix data of patches from Netlogo in a excel file?

Tags: netlogo

I am particularly working with the "Flocking" model of Netlogo. What i want is to select an agent and look if any other agent is there for the next 3 patches of the selected agent.I want to check it for all around the agent so i will get a matrix form of data and save it in a excel/cvs file.

Comment: What you're actually looking for is somewhat unclear. 

Do you want each turtle to look at the 3 patches in front of it and output to a file what's there? Or to look at all patches in a radius of 3 units and output what's there? What is the output factor of interest (density, distance, size, color)? What do you want your matrix to be comprised of? Do you want this for every tick, at the end of every run, for every parameter, for every turtle? Please specify so we can help you better.  It's also usually a good idea to provide some coding attempt/reproducible problem or code fragment to use

Comment: First of all sorry for the mistakes. Yes i want the turtles to look at 3 patches but not in a radius manner but more in a matrix manner. I just want to see if there are any other turtle in that matrix, just a Boolean value. Like if there is a turtle the value  should be 1 and if there isn't the value should be 0 of the matrix. I want the data for every tick and for every turtle. Hope this clears everything.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately I don't have a definitive answer for you, but I'd imagine you'll want to do something of the sort:

```
globals
[ output_matrix]
patches-own 
    [occupied?]
to setup
clear-all
reset-ticks
  create-turtles 50
  set output_matrix []
end
to go
  move 
  tick
end  
to move  
  ask turtles [set heading random-float 361 forward random-float 2 ]
  ask patches with [count turtles-here > 0] [set occupied? 1]
  ask patches with [count turtles-here = 0] [set occupied? 0]
  check_surroundings
end
to check_surroundings
  ask turtles [ ifelse any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1 
    [set output_matrix lput 1 output_matrix]
    [set output_matrix lput 0 output_matrix]]
  ask turtles [ ifelse any? turtles-on patch-ahead 2 
    [set output_matrix lput 1 output_matrix]
    [set output_matrix lput 0 output_matrix]]
  ask turtles [ ifelse any? turtles-on patch-ahead 3 
    [set output_matrix lput 1 output_matrix]
    [set output_matrix lput 0 output_matrix]]
 end
```

That will give you 2 options. 1 you could use behavior space to output the full patch list every tick in to a file (which you'd specify in behavior space) with a simple 0 or 1 for each patch to represent whether it's occupied or not. The second option would be to use the output_matrix list this creates (not sure what your end game is). That will give you a series of three 0's and 1's for each turtle at every tick (if you want to estimate how the aggregation forms over time this might be more useful).

You may also want to look in to the output-print and file-open/file-close primitives

I'm sure if you generate some sample code, the community will be able to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

```
globals [rpts]  ;write your code to set global only once

to test
  ca
  set rpts moore-offsets 3
  ask n-of 50 patches [sprout 1 [set color red]]
  ask one-of turtles [
    ask patches at-points rpts [set pcolor yellow]
    print any? other turtles-on patches at-points rpts
  ]
end

to-report moore-offsets [#n] ;includes center ...
  let _result []
  let _xs n-values (1 + 2 * #n) [? - 3]
  foreach _xs [
    let _y ?
    foreach _xs [
      let _x ?
      set _result lput (list _x _y) _result
    ]
  ]
  report _result
end
```